# subtract two rows which are result of group bc clause

Tags: sql, presto, difference

I am having a case where I have raw data I am grouping it according to year and then I have to subtract the year to get the value but it is not working. example data is

```html
year, profit,gross
2020   252563.02E9   352563.02E9
2022   102563.02E9    352563.02E9
2021   352563.02E9    352563.02E9
2022   482563.02E9    352563.02E9
2021   002563.02E9     352563.02E9
2020   10231.02E9     352563.02E9
2022   345633.25E9    352563.00E9
with
cal as
(
SELECT t.year, 
cast(sum(t.profit) as decimal(17,2))  profit ,
cast(sum(t.gross)as decimal(17,2)) gross
--  t.srad_agency_provision - LAG(t.srad_agency_provision) OVER(ORDER BY year)  as diff_previous_year
from shoptable t
group by t.year
order by t.year  
)
```

after this query I got following result

```html
year  profit   gross
2020  22311834.85   1030294447.42
2021  26598154.02   1704662197.69
2022  25234347.02    1841593955.36
```

Now I want to subtract the  profit and gross from previos one.like 2021 from 2022, 2020 from 2021 I am trying

```html
diff as (
select
  t.year,
  t.profit,
  (t.profit) - LAG(t.profit) OVER(ORDER BY year)  as diff_profit
  from
  shop table t 
  )
```

but it is showing for whole each value in 2020 and so on. I want to subtract the results of group by clause which I got in previous query.
Expected output is

```html
year  profit   gross                diff_profit    diff gross  
2020  22311834.85   1030294447.42    4,286,319.17    674,367,750.27
2021  26598154.02   1704662197.69   -1363807         136,931,757.67
2022  25234347.02    1841593955.36
```

How can I achieve it?thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not you just apply you window function to the results of `cal`. Something along this lines:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(year, profit,gross) as (
    values
    ('2020', 252563, 352563),
    ('2022', 102563, 352563),
    ('2021', 352563, 352563),
    ('2022', 482563, 352563),
    ('2021', 002563, 352563),
    ('2020', 10231 , 352563),
    ('2022', 345633, 352563)
),
cal as (
    SELECT t.year,
    sum(t.profit) profit ,
    sum(t.gross) gross
    from dataset t
    group by t.year
    order by t.year
)

-- query
select *,
    (profit) - LAG(profit) OVER(ORDER BY year) as diff_profit,
    (gross) - LAG(gross) OVER(ORDER BY year) as diff_gross
from cal;
```

Comment: yes, thank you.  some timeI do stupid mistakes

Comment: @user19 NP, we all do =) Was glad to help!